# Invalid Keystore format exception while configuring Wildfly 8.0.0 with VAULT to encrypt keystore password

Tags: java, ssl, wildfly, keystore

I have configured wildfly 8.0.0 server with JDK 1.8 u162 for providing HTTPS support to my application by creating self signed certificate. To configure it successfully I have specified keystore password in clear text in the standalone.xml file and it is working properly.
Now I want to make the keystore password in encrypted mode instead of clear text. To do that I have used VAULT script and performed all the require steps to generate the VAULT.dat file and  tag. After specifying require settings in the standalone.xml file, when I started my wild-fly server it has given me java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format exception and due to that system was not deployed.
I have performed following steps:
1) To generate keystore file I have used following command and followed the instructions.
    **keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias vault -keystore osp_keystore.jks -validity 365 -keysize 2048**

2) I have opened the VAULT window (vault.bat) to encrypt the keystore password. I have performed all the require steps which has given me following information for configuring in the standlone.xml file.

```
<vault>
  <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_URL" value="D:\osp\standalone\configuration\osp_keystore.jks"/>
  <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" value="MASK-ZCA9zDtIIr7BbsQlgnChk"/>
  <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_ALIAS" value="ospvault"/>
  <vault-option name="SALT" value="ASDF1234"/>
  <vault-option name="ITERATION_COUNT" value="50"/>
  <vault-option name="ENC_FILE_DIR" value="D:\osp\standalone\configuration\vault\"/>
</vault>

Vault Block:keystore
Attribute Name:password
VAULT::keystore::password::1
```

3) I have configured standalone.xml file with following tags.
    a) Specified above  tag in between the `</extensions>` and `<management>` tags.
    b) Under the `<security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">` tag added following tag.

```
<server-identities>
                 ssl><keystore path=" osp_keystore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="${VAULT::keystore::password::1}" /></ssl>
                </server-identities>
```

c) Under the `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.0">` tag bind the ApplicationRealm with HTTPS.

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

the keystore for the server-identities and the keystore for the vault, are two different keystores. 
Example for generating a keystore:

```
keytool -genseckey -alias vault -storetype jceks -keyalg AES -keysize 128 -storepass vault123 -keypass vault123 -validity 365 -keystore ${jboss-config}\vault\vault.keystore
```

and then in standalone.xml:

```
<vault-option name="KEYSTORE_URL" value="${jboss-config}/vault/vault.keystore"/>
```

Highly recommended to read: 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.1/html/security_guide/Create_a_Java_Keystore_to_Store_Sensitive_Strings

Comment: the command you shared generates: keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format